Swift faster way to retrieve exif data from PHAsset
I'm working on a photos app on iOS, where I have to extract the camera information of user's photos for displaying.
The problem I am facing is that the process turns out to be extremely slow and sometimes each request takes about 1-2 seconds for which if you factor in a large photos library mostly residing on the cloud it can take forever.
I want to find out if there is a better way get the exif data out of a PHAsset (photo or video) that is fast and efficient.
If it matters, I only want to access this information to display and not write back to the photo or video or perform any content editing.
Below is how I access this information currently (several methods) and as mentioned above, and it is a very time consuming operation which is not feasible.

func fetchCameraInfo(asset: PHAsset, completion: @escaping (Result<String?, Error>) -> Void) {
        if asset.mediaType == .image { // Images
            
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            
            // Method 1
            // This requests full sized data from the cloud and is extremely slow for raw files
            PHCachingImageManager().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: asset, options: options) { data, _, _, info in
                // do the error checks with info dictionary and optional data
                guard let data, let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil),
                      let metaData = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as? [String: Any] else {
                    completion(.failure(PhotoLibraryError.unknown))
                    return
                }
                
                let cameraInfo: String? = extractCameraDataFromExif(metaData)
                completion(.success(cameraInfo))
            }
            
            // Method 2
            // If I request a smaller image to save on network activity, the returned image does not contain the camera info but contains just pixel and dimensions info
            PHCachingImageManager().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: .init(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .default, options: options) { image, info in
                guard let image, let data = image.pngData(),
                      let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil),
                      let metaData = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as? [String: Any] else {
                    completion(.failure(PhotoLibraryError.unknown)); return
                }
                
                let cameraInfo: String? = extractCameraDataFromExif(metaData)
                completion(.success(cameraInfo))
            }
            
            // Method 3
            // Use content editing options. This too is extremely expensive operation to run in batches just for exif data
            let inputOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
            inputOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

            asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: inputOptions) { input, info in
                guard let input, let imageURL = input.fullSizeImageURL,
                      let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL as CFURL, nil),
                      let metaData = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as? [String: Any] else {
                    completion(.failure(PhotoLibraryError.unknown)); return
                }
                
                let cameraInfo: String? = extractCameraDataFromExif(metaData)
                completion(.success(cameraInfo))
            }
        } else { // Videos
            let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
            
            PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: options) { avAsset, _, info in
                guard let avAsset else {
                    completion(.failure(PhotoLibraryError.unknown))
                    return
                }
                
                for item in avAsset.commonMetadata {
                    // check for item and it's keys and extract data
                }
            }
        }
        
        func extractCameraDataFromExif(_ exif: [String: Any]) -> String? {
            return nil
        }
    }

